# How to insert additional characters into a PostgreSQL Database Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work with the programming language Java and I would to insert data with additional characters into a database table.

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO bv_usergroup (id, active, description, deleted) VALUES (1, TRUE, Administrator \(Company\), FALSE);
```

The additional character is the sign "(" and ")". How can I solve this problem? And is it correct to insert boolean values how you can see it in my sql example?

Thenaks and Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 0):

Character literals (aka "strings") have to enclosed in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO bv_usergroup 
   (id, active, description, deleted) 
VALUES 
   (1, TRUE, 'Administrator (Company)', FALSE);
```

For more details on how to specifiy literals, please see the manual:
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS